# How does one determine the route of an Web API 2.2 Action implemented in a base class?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Assume for a moment that I have an abstract controller

```
public abstract class ResourceController<TResource> : ApiController where TResource: Resource,new() 
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FindById([FromUri] string id)
    {
         TResource resource = null;
         // go fetch the resource from a database or something
         return Ok(resource)
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(TResource resource)
    {
         TResource resource = null;
         // go create the resource or something
         return CreatedAtRoute("XXXXX", new { id = resource.Id }, resource);
    }

    // more methods
}


[RoutePrefix("foo")]
public class FooResourceController : ResourceController<Foo> 
{
}

[RoutePrefix("baa")]
public class BaaResourceController : ResourceController<Baa> 
{
}

public class Resource
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // some other properties all resources shared 
}
```

At this stage all the actions work, except for creating a new resource. Without overriding the `Create` method in every subclass, how do I find the correct route of the `FindById` of the respective controllers from the ResourceController Create method?

For example, if I create a `foo` resource with id `123` then it would return `foo/123`. If I created a resource `baa` with id 456, then it woulds return `baa/456`.

I'm unable to name the route using attributes, since only one can exist for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I fixed it by using the Created method in combination with the calling url.
This will only work if yout post doesn't have a dedicated template

My get:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var codetabel = await _reader.GetAsync(id);
            var model = Mapper.Map<TCodeTabelModel>(codetabel);
            return OkResult(model);
        }
        catch ....
    }
```

And post:

```
[HttpPost()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> InsertAsync(TCodeTabelModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequestResult(ModelState);

            try
            {
                var entity = Mapper.Map<TCodeTabelEntity>(model);
                var insertedEntity = await _writer.InsertAsync(entity);

                return Created($"{Request.Path.Value}/{insertedEntity.Id}" , Mapper.Map<TCodeTabelModel>(insertedEntity));
            }
            catch ....
        }
```